# Java GC: Are rows of generic arrays independent objects?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, garbage-collection

When i do the following:

```
public double[] someFn()
{
    double[][] b = new double[5][5];
    return b[2];
}
```

is the rest of buffer b ready for the trashbin or does the still somewhere in-use ref to the 2nd row stop the whole array b from getting collected?

As im talking 'bout generic arrays, i cant test for finalization…

Comment: While they are allocated as separate objects which can live on their own, they are typically allocated continuously in memory and remain together in memory after a GC (assuming they are all retained via one reference)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, each element of `b` is *just* a reference to a `double[]`. Each one can be a reference to an independent object - or several elements could refer to the same array, or have null values.

There's no "backlink" from the element to the array containing it.

Basically, you should think of "multidimensional" arrays as just normal arrays where the element type *happens* to be another array. So for example:

```
String foo() {
    String[] array = getStrings();
    return array[0];
}
```

The string reference returned by the method doesn't know anything about the array, and nor does the string object it refers to. It's exactly the same way with arrays of arrays.

Comment: Where do you find this type of information?  How Java internally handles memory allocation situations such as the one described by the OP?  Is there a specification or something similar I could read to get an understanding? Or is it simply reading the source?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Well the Java Language Specification is a good start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The other elements of b will ready to be gc-ed after someFn() returns,because you can't get any references of them.
I wrote a small program to prove that:

```
public class GCDemo {

static class OneMB {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    String name;

    public OneMB(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(name + " gc-ed");
    }
}

public static OneMB[] someFn() {
    OneMB[][] b = new OneMB[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            b[i][j] = new OneMB(i + "-" + j);
        }
    }
    return b[2];
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    OneMB[] b2 = someFn();
    System.gc();
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    System.out.println("after b2 is released");
    b2 = null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

}

the output is

0-2 gc-ed

1-2 gc-ed

1-1 gc-ed

0-1 gc-ed

0-0 gc-ed

1-0 gc-ed

after b2 is released

2-2 gc-ed

2-1 gc-ed

2-0 gc-ed